# How to delete a MySQL row that only the logged-in user created

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I made a website that creates 'awards' and user has to login.  I am trying to create a 'delete' button so that the user can delete awards he created. The problem with the code I created, the user can delete ANY award that any user created.  I need it so that only awards that the logged-in user can be deleted by the same logged-in user.

```
//deletes the award from awards table
    app.post('/Update_Award', function(request, response) {
    //app.delete('/Delete_Award', function(request, response) {
        var connection = request.app.get('pool');
        if (request.session.loggedin) {
            //delete query - this delete query works but it can delete ANY award by ANY user 
            //connection.query('DELETE FROM award WHERE id = ?', [request.body.id], function(error, results, fields) {      
            //I tried this query so that only the logged-in user can delete its own created award
            //but this does not delete anything at all
            **connection.query('DELETE FROM award WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE username = ?)', [request.session.username], function(error, results, fields) { **
                if (error) {
                    throw error;
                } else 
                    var context = {};
                    connection.query('SELECT * FROM award', function(error, results, fields) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        context.awards = results;
                        connection.query('SELECT id, title, defaultDescription FROM awardType;', function(error, results, fields) {
                        context.awardTypes = {};
                        results.forEach(function(el) {
                            context.awardTypes[el.id] = el.title;
                        });
                        response.render('Update_Award.html', { awards: context.awards, awardTypes: context.awardTypes, msg: 'Successfully deleted!' });
                        });
                    } 
                    });
            }); 
        } 
        });
```

I've been stuck with this problem so any help would be much appreciated.  So far, it doesn't output any error but it cannot delete a row.

The award table has the "isserId" which is the "id" of the user in the accounts table which contains all the users.

Comment: does the award table have owner column? if yes then enable the button only in case if the owner id and logged in user id is matching. Do the same validation before delete statement in server side.

Comment: The award table has the "isserId" which is the "id" of the user in the accounts table which contains all the users. - how would I be able to enable the button for that?

Comment: while rendering the view you'll have to check if award created id and logged in user id is not matching then don't render the button.